# How to get backgroud color of QtFrame in PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I know how to set it:

`color_frame.setStyleSheet("QWidget { background-color: blue}")`

But how do I read the color value (may be in hex, I don't care) of the QtFrame background ?

Please note, I'm not looking for:

`color_frame.palette().highlight().color().name()`

since it doesn't seem to ge me the value of QtFrame background color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`highlight()` won't give you the background since the `Highlight` role is used for selections.

By default, widgets use the `Window` role (unless specified by [`setBackgroundRole()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setBackgroundRole)) to draw the background, so you need to use the related [`window()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpalette.html#window) function to get it:

```
color_frame.palette().window().color().name()
```

Or just use [`color()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpalette.html#color) with the related role as argument:

```
color_frame.palette().color(QPalette.Window).name()
```

To be slightly more sure about it, use the current background role:

```
color_frame.palette().color(color_frame.backgroundRole()).name()
```

Note that:

- in some cases, the style could use the color set by the palette (including those set in the stylesheet) in slightly different ways and the drawing could differ from what's expected; remember that palette colors are only used as reference, it's up to the style to "decide" how strict be about that;
- setting a global property for a parent widget is normally not a good idea, if a generic (o no) selector is used: some complex widgets require that as soon as a *single* property is set, all others must be set too. This is notably the case of QComboBox and QScrollBar; you should use more specific [selector](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#selector-types) (possibly using the class or the object name);
- the only color properties that are readable from the palette after setting a stylesheet are the `color` (applies to `WindowText`, `Text` and `ButtonText` roles), `background`(`Window`, `Base` and `Button`), `selection-color` (`Highlight`), `selection-background-color` (`HighlightedText`) and `alternate-base`  (`AlternateBase`); all other color roles are automatically computed based on the above; any other property, specifically those set for subcontrols, are *not* available;